# how to create dynamic website using PHP, MySQL and MS Excel

Tags: php, mysql, database, excel

I want to create a travel agency website in PHP with MySQL, the requirements are back end admin control and an excel file to add data so that can be uploaded from admin area to display contents on website.

Where should i start? any tutorial will be helpful btw i know how to build dynamic websites with dreamweaver.

Comment: I'm sorry to say this sounds like a terrible idea to me.  There are many easy to install and easy to use CMS packages which allow user roles to modify site content without needing some fragile Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Putting the burden of your initial research effort on the community seems to me quite unfair.

Comment: Who set the Excel requirement? If that is your client's wish, I would probably spend some time explaining what could go wrong, and push instead for a CMS.

Comment: As someone who spends most every waking hour creating libraries to allow PHP to work with Excel, I'd recommend against this.... a straight CMS without any reference to Excel would be a far better option

Comment: If your requirement for a spreadsheet if for email and distribution. Your better of like suggested, using a database to store your info, and import or export what you need when you need it into spreadsheet or csv format.

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal utilising an Excel file for the Administration of a site; a Content Management System would be the best option.

If the client has their heart set on using Excel, the simplest and quickest way is to upload the file by phpMyAdmin - although that would mean giving your clients access to that area - and the field headings in the file would need to be the same (and naive clients may add headings left right and centre).

As replied earlier, explain the disadvantages of utilising Excel, show them something like this > http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/ - a Javascript datagrid.

But CMS is the best option.

Mike